# Getting og membership type in template.tpl.php

Tags: theming, users, organic-groups

I want to obtain the organic groups role-id of a node/comment-author in node.tpl.php and comment.tpl.php.

I can't find an array that provides this information.

I want to add a class based on the authors membership type.

Dummycode:

```
<div id="header" class="<?php if ($author->rid == 7): print 'class-7'; endif; ?>">
```

How to do this for nodes and comments?

Note: for normal (non-organic-group) roles I use:

```
<?php if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)): print 'admin-type'; endif; ?>
```

Which works ok, I want similar usage for organic group roles.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it with this page: http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/og/og!og.module/7.x-2.x

Comment: Instead of editing your questions and/or commenting, you can make it into an answer by filling out the **Your Answer** section below.

Comment: I cant I have not enough reputationpoints and have to wait 8 hours before I can answer my own question.

Comment: If you can remember to answer after the 8 hour window, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Found the anwser:
This goes in node.tpl.php (tested on Drupal 7, Organic groups 7.x-2.3)

```
<?php if (og_context()) {
  $group = og_context();
  $userid = user_load($node->uid);
  $roles = og_get_user_roles('node', $group[gid], $uid = $userid->uid, $include = FALSE);
  }
?>
```

Then use it with something like:

```
<?php if(in_array('test member', $roles)): print '<span>Testuser</span>'; endif; ?>
```

For comments it's a little different:

```
<?php if (og_context()) {
  $group = og_context();
  $roles = og_get_user_roles('node', $group[gid], $uid = $comment->uid, $include = FALSE);
  }
?>
```

Works only on pages where groupcontext is available!

Comment: Hello. Code-only answers are of pretty low value: if code cease to work (due to API changes for example), they are simply worthless, and if it does work, it leaves future readers clueless about *why* and *how*. Could you please expand it?

Comment: please add description and steps and also where to add this code.

Comment: Done, you are right, I hate it when I find answers that work on older versions only.